# c# scrollviewer and dispatch timer firing problems

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, timer, scrollviewer

So I am having a problem with the firing of my dispatch timer when scrolling through a scrollviewer housing about 100 small rectangles in stackpanels.

My dispatch timer is firing every 400 ms, playing a sound every tick of 400 ms. If I don't touch the scrollviewer, the ticks fire as they should. However if I start to move the scrollviewer around, the ticks can be anywhere from 600-1300 ms or so.

My question is, what can I use such that I can have an event happen every 400 seconds or so that wont get delayed by scrolling through a scrollviewer?

This is for a WP7 App and the rectangles were made with xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DispatcherTimer fires on the dispatcher (or UI) thread.
You're manipulation of the scrollviewer and the redrawing of the rectangles based on your scrolling will also happen on the UI thread.

The simplest solution would be to use a regular Timer and have that fire every 400ms.